# Generate multipage PDF from a UIWebView in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, pdf-generation

I am loading www.stackoverflow.com into a UIWebView in my application. I have used the following code snippet to generate pdf :

```
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdf.pdf"];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

CGRect PDFRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(PDFRect, nil);

CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1, 1);
[self.webView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

When the pdf is generated, only the PDF of 1st visible page of website is created. stackoverflow site has several pages down the the screen,its scrollable. I need the entire pages of the site to be converted to PDF.
Now, when I generate the PDF, it consists of only 1 page. I want PDF with multiple pages,according to the content size height of the website loaded.

What should be done to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution :

```
- (IBAction)showWebView:(id)sender {
  self.webView.hidden = NO;
  self.webView.delegate=self;
  [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
  NSMutableURLRequest * request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]];
  [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   //Check here if still webview is loding the content
    if (webView.isLoading)
    return;
    else //finished loading
    [self performSelector:@selector(createPDF) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}


-(void)createPDF
{
 CGRect origframe = self.webView.frame;
 NSString *heightStr = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]; // Get the height of our webView
 int height = [heightStr intValue];

// Size of the view in the pdf page
CGFloat maxHeight   = 568;
CGFloat maxWidth    = self.webView.frame.size.width;
int pages = ceil(height / maxHeight);
// gets the total no:of pages needed in PDF

[self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, maxWidth, maxHeight)];

NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfFileName = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdf.pdf"];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

int i = 0;
for ( ; i < pages; i++)
{
    if (maxHeight * (i+1) > height)
    { // Check to see if page draws more than the height of the UIWebView
        CGRect f = [self.webView frame];
        f.size.height -= (((i+1) * maxHeight) - height);
        [self.webView setFrame: f];
    }

    // Specify the size of the pdf page
    CGRect PDFRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(PDFRect, nil);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Move the context for the margins
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1, 1);
    // offset the webview content so we're drawing the part of the webview for the current page
    [[[self.webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, maxHeight * i) animated:NO];
    // draw the layer to the pdf, ignore the "renderInContext not found" warning.
    [self.webView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
}
// all done with making the pdf
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
// Restore the webview and move it to the top.
[self.webView setFrame:origframe];
[[[self.webView subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];

}
```